# Umbraco - How can I get Publish at/Remove at date using C#

Tags: c#, api, razor, umbraco

How can I get Publish at/Remove at date using C# in Umbraco?

Comment: Please note that they fixed some bugs related to the publishAt in the 4.7.1 release.

Comment: hmm yeah.. but we have an old version Umbraco site to manage.. so need to find workarounds for probs related to these..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to access the ReleaseDate and ExpireDate of the Document object.

```
var doc = new Document(nodeId);
var publishAt = doc.ReleaseDate;
var removeAt = doc.ExpireDate;
```

Comment: Thanks for the code.. its perfect but Umbraco doesn't seem to provide the ReleaseDate and ExpireDate if we use  

foreach(Document doc in rootDoc.Children)
{
}

Comment: Does this query gives the same result
SELECT D.nodeId, D.releaseDate, D.expireDate FROM dbo.cmsDocument D 
                WHERE D.newest = 1 AND 
                (
                 ( D.releaseDate IS NOT NULL AND D.releaseDate <= GETDATE() ) 
                 OR 
                 ( D.expireDate IS NOT NULL AND D.expireDate <= GETDATE() ) 
                );

Answer (score 0):

Your post helped me a lot. Thank you!
I'm a novice on Umbraco, and I have a little comment.
To get it to work we need to import the businesslogic namespace:

```
@using umbraco.cms.businesslogic.web;
```

It would be obvious for experienced users, but can be useful to novices like me.