# Check if it is a scheduled publish?

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I am trying to check if a publish event, is a scheduled event.
I have tried checking `entity.ReleaseDate.HasValue`, but it seems to be empty no matter what.

Does it get cleared earlier than `ContentService.Publishing` or should i check something else?

Answer (score 0):

This post might hold some answers for you:
https://our.umbraco.org/forum/umbraco-7/using-umbraco-7/55045-Getting-the-Publish-at-property-in-a-view#comment-201006

Or this answer from Tim Saunders:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7444389/1435590

Basically, you can try it like this:

```
var doc = new Document(nodeId);
var publishAt = doc.ReleaseDate;
var removeAt = doc.ExpireDate;
```